# Is there a way to log CPU load?

Tags: performance, cpu, logfiles

I need to examine how my CPU is performing. I could simply open the task manager, but I will have to sit in front of the monitor long time. My problem is that CPU seems to be spiking or overloading and crashing all the programs that are running. So, I want to be able to log it somewhere say every second or so. Is there way to log CPU load?

Comment: http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/plog/ <- Tracks per process and not the system as a whole.

Comment: I am looking for overall cpu load not per process

Comment: @goldilocks: with a theme like that, the software must be trustworthy :P

Comment: @goldilocks I have tried the answer. Apparently, syrupy is not part of the repository and my Pi already has `top` but that doesn't log.

Comment: I'll reopen this since it is a bit more focussed than the duplicate; if all you want is CPU time there are various ways to do this.  [See here for some ideas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123908) (I'll recommend just skipping to the second half of my answer there about parsing `/proc/stat`).

Answer (score 1):

You can run `top` without reloading and write its output to a log to analyze it later.

`while sleep 1; do top -n1 >> cpu.log; done`

Comment: I suppose you run this on the terminal. I did that and got `bash syntax error` it is complaining about the semicolon.

Comment: whats your bash version? i tested it with `GNU bash, Version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` (fixed semicolon)

Comment: mine is `4.3.30(1)-release`